# Eigen - get a matrix from a map?

Tags: c++, eigen

I'm using Eigen::Map to get access to create an object from a C-array. I would like to save that object as a member variable of type MatrixXf.

How do I do that? I couldn't find a way to convert the Map to a Matrix.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use `operator=`:

```
MatrixXd mat;
mat = Map<MatrixXd>(data, rows, cols);
```

Comment: does this do a copy? or do I need to make sure `data` does not go out of scope?

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same issue but vector is constant, then you have to do it following way as @ggael proposed,

```
Eigen::MatrixXd mat = Eigen::Map<const Eigen::MatrixXd>(x.data(), rows, cols);
```

where x can be either `const Eigen::VectorXd x` or `const std::vector<double>` or C type array.